# ubuntu 16.04 on iMac mid 2011 unity desktop stops responding

Tags: 16.04, unity, mac

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 on my iMac (mid 2011 model) and everything seems to work fine, until (randomly) the unity desktop completely freezes.

I can still move the mouse but the clicks doesn't get any response and I can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn Key</kbd> to show any tty. I can still login to the machine through ssh where I can run `sudo systemctl restart lightdm.service` to bring back the desktop (losing all my work).

I have looked in `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and dmesg for any error related to the problem (video card messages, unity messages, etc) but I have not found anything relevant.

I also tried to upgrade to 16.10 (but I prefer to stuck with LTS release if there is a solution) and the problem persits.

Does anybody had similar issue or has any clues of where to look to get more info of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

it helps to know which imac version.. imac4,1 imac5,1 etc.

This page can help determine which one you have:

> https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac_(Intel-based)

Info is also located on your system and likely found by cross-referencing the info found in "About This Computer" near System Settings menu.

The symptoms you describe are similar to what I've seen on a local imac8,1 when screen memory is exceeded.

To minimize issues, reduce memory overhead on things that are not necessary. For example, simplify the *Display Background* in *System Settings* to a solid color. Also in *System Settings > Appearance*, make sure "enable workspaces" is turned-off.

Oh, and make sure the system is not using the vendor supplied video driver. Use the generic video driver supplied by Ubuntu --even though the system may suggest otherwise. If there are any bugs, Ubuntu will work to fix it; The OEM does not provide support for their drivers --especially under an open source application such as Ubuntu.

cheers,

ps. Updating to Ubuntu 16.04LTS will solve at least one related bug.

Comment: iMac mid 2011 could mean iMac12,1 or 12,2 in the other notation. However, GPU differs even under a single configuration according to the page you linked. Shouldn’t you rather ask for the actual GPU?

Comment: I have a few years experience with different Macs on Ubuntu. This is fairly typical of over-memory symptoms for Macs with Nvidia/Radeon/AMD and also intel workstations with similar AMD low memory graphics cards. These suggestions tend to alleviate cases that are not heavy on graphics.

Comment: I tried to say the first part of your answer (before “The symptoms“) seems  superfluous to me. Same for “ps.”, OP is running 16.04 already.

Comment: @Melebius, a few of the graphics cards are Intel. Suggestions may not apply to Intel video.  As for OP running 16.10, I misread OP having installed earlier version. Regardless, certain imac video issues are fixed only on 16.+ The documentation on it is fairly obtuse, involves closed/rejected bugs ie  not fixed for earlier and still supported LTS, since 16LTS fixed the problem. I've been trying to find bug url.. it was long an windy.. anyway.. Edit or not. I'm just trying to make answer more useful for anyone else with similar circumstances. cheers

Comment: The system is an imac12,2 (based on the wikipedia link you posted) with an AMD Radeon HD 6770M 512 MB graphic card, it's a discrete card but I had been running ubuntu with unity on more discrete cards at my work PC. The system is not using the vendor driver because there is no fglrx available in 16.04.